# Combining ImageMagick import/montage commands into one-liner

Tags: imagemagick, screenshot, imagemagick-montage

Long story short **from the command line** I need to take a screenshot, crop two areas of that screenshot and join them back together side-by-side.

The separate stages which work fine look like this:

```
$> import -window root -crop '1280x400+0+0' left.png

$> import -window root -crop '1280x400+0+400' right.png

$> montage -geometry 1280x400 left.png right.png out.png
```

However, I'm not sure how to combine this into one command.

OS is Linux (Raspbian) if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do any cropping as part of a `magick import` so I'll import and forward to a regular `magick` command for processing.

To mimic your approach, that would be:

```
magick import -window root png:- | magick png:- \
  \( -clone 0 -crop 1280x400+0+0   \) \
  \( -clone 0 -crop 1280x400+0+400 \) \
  -delete 0 +append result.png
```

That first grabs the screen with `import` and pipes it on as a PNG to a second command that clones the image and crops the left half, clones it again and crops the right half, deletes the original and places the two crops side-by-side.

---

There is an easier way that works for you though. If you crop without an offset, all the cropped areas will remain in your stack:

```
magick import -window root png:- | magick png: -crop x50% +append result.png
```

---

**Note**: I am also using 50% of the height as the crop to save me having to do any maths

**Note**: If you want a magenta gap between the two halves, add `-background magenta` near the start and replace `+append` with `+smush 10` to place them 10 pixels apart.